# Choose how to order Django Model choices

Tags: python, django, django-models

When displaying the below choices, I want to be able to order them as follows Preparation, Review, Update, Finalised and Completed.

Right now, they are ordered alphabetically.

The below is a simple model:

```
class Choice(models.Model):
status_choices = [
        ("", "Select Current Status"),
        ("Preparation", "Preparation"),
        ("Review", "Review"),
        ("Update", "Update"),
        ("Finalised", "Finalised"),
        ("Completed", "Completed"),
    ]

    current_status = models.CharField(
        max_length=32,
        choices = status_choices,
        default = "Select current status",
    )

    class Meta:
            ordering = ["current_status"]
```

I read that assigning a number in the Tuple can allow them to be ordered, which I tried per the below:

```
status_choices = [
        ("", "Select Current Status"),
        ("1", "Preparation"),
        ("2", "Review"),
        ("3", "Update"),
        ("4", "Finalised"),
        ("5", "Completed"),
    ]
```

However, this made no difference.
I have also tried:

```
    PREPARATION = "a"
    REVIEW = "b"
    UPDATE = "c"
    FINALISED = "d"
    COMPLETED = "e"

    status_choices = [
        ("", "Select Current Status"),
        (PREPARATION, "Preparation"),
        (REVIEW, "Review"),
        (UPDATE, "Update"),
        (FINALISED, "Finalised"),
        (COMPLETED, "Completed"),
    ]
```

I feel like this should be very simple but maybe not.

Comment: i don't see in dhango.db.models.fields.charfield and in django.form.fields.select - anywhere a function to sort choices. Please provvide us the code, how you render this form? Where you find this "I read that assigning a number in the Tuple can allow them to be ordered", if that true, you receive: '0', '1', '10','11', '2', '3'. ,'4','5','6','7'

Comment: I've added the form I use to select the choices. Once the form is submitted, I want to be able to sort the choices as mentioned above rather than alphabetically. I pass the model into the template through the view context. As mentioned, the aim is to order the model output by Preparation, Review, Update, Finalised and Completed as opposed to alphabetically `ordering = ["current_status"]`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure how ordering of numerals in charfields goes, but you might try making the number explicit by changing the field to a smallintegerfield like so:

```
class Choice(models.Model):

PREPARATION = 1
REVIEW = 2
UPDATE = 3
FINALISED = 4
COMPLETED = 5

status_choices = [
        ("", "Select Current Status"),
        (PREPARATION, "Preparation"),
        (REVIEW, "Review"),
        (UPDATE, "Update"),
        (FINALISED, "Finalised"),
        (COMPLETED, "Completed"),
    ]

    current_status = models.SmallIntegerField(
        choices = status_choices,
        default = 0
    )

    class Meta:
            ordering = ["current_status"]
```

One advantage of this approach is that you can use a more readable reference to the model's constant while still having the benefits of the numeric ordering, eg,

```
 if choice_instance.current_status > Choice.UPDATE:
```

I wasn't sure from your question if you were also having problems with the ordering of the select widget itself.  If the above doesn't help with the widget, you might try explicitly referring to the status_choices list, eg,

```
  widgets = {
        'current_status' : forms.Select(choices = Choice.status_choices, attrs={'placeholder':'Select Current Status', 'class':'table_data_request_status'}),
        }
```

Comment: Hi SamSparx, thanks for this. It doesn't have to be by number. As mentioned in the above, that was something I tried but didn't work. I'm having no issue with the form. The aim is to order the model output by Preparation, Review, Update, Finalised and Completed as opposed to alphabetically ordering = ["current_status"]

Comment: I've also added an additional way of looking at through `"a", "b", "c",` etc. but it still doesn't work

Comment: These methods should work.  How are you outputting the model? Is there an order by in the query?

Comment: There is no order in the query. The ordering is just coming from the `Meta` class. Do you mean that ``"a', "b", "c", `` should work to help me order my model?

Comment: Yes.  It may be worth noting that any old values won't be changed just by changing the options available, because it's still a charfield and so the old values are still acceptable to the database (see https://adamj.eu/tech/2020/01/22/djangos-field-choices-dont-constrain-your-data/).  Thus if you look at choice_instance.current_status and it outputs "preparation", that won't have the new value of 'a' for ordering purposes - you'll have to loop through and perform a subsitition on existing records.